# Confusion about malloc an array of struct

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, malloc

Ok, so I  have the following struct

```
struct node {
    int visited;
    struct node **depend;
};
```

and I am trying to allocate it dynamically using the following

```
fscanf(iStream, "%d %d", &nTasks, &nRules);

    graph = (struct node *) malloc(nTasks * sizeof(struct node));
```

but Eclipse shows an

> ..\GraphSort.c:62:18: warning: implicit declaration of function
>   'malloc' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]   graph = (struct node *)
>   malloc(nTasks * sizeof(struct node));
>                     ^

and

> ..\GraphSort.c:62:26: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of
>   built-in function 'malloc' [enabled by default]   graph = (struct node
>   *) malloc(nTasks * sizeof(struct node));
>                             ^

What I don't understand is why. Isn't an array represented as a pointer to the first element?

Also a little further I have this declaration which shows no warnings

```
fscanf(iStream, "%d, %d", &taskId, &dependencies);
        graph[taskId-1].visited = 0;
        graph[taskId-1].depend = (struct node **) malloc(dependencies * sizeof(struct node *));
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: Have you included `stdlib.h` ?

Comment: And this is why you should [never cast the result of malloc in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)...

Comment: Is it wrong to cast it. I never quite got it. It seems to me that you should show what you want. Might make finding errors easier

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`implicit declaration of function 'malloc'` is an indicator that you haven't included the proper header file that tells your program how to call `malloc`. Try adding to the beginning of your program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Your other bit of code is not a "declaration," it's just a series of statements. The compiler will only warn you once about failing to declare `malloc()` for each file that it compiles.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you just forgot to include `<stdlib.h>`.